# Integrating by parts of exponential functions

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I read the book [Classical Fields Theory](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1953kft..book.....I/abstract) (in russian), and I met an integral taken by Landau's method:

[image]

Integrating by parts, in (8.4) we have

\begin{equation*}
\frac1{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \frac{e^{ik(x - x')} - 1}{k^2} = -\frac{|x - x'|}{2}
\end{equation*}

How the modulus ($|x- x'|$) came from integral is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: The cosine is an even function and the sine is odd.

Comment: Of course this is only for real $x,x'$.

Comment: @GEdgar values are real

Comment: Integrating by part $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \frac{e^{ika} - 1}{k^2}$$=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{ika} - 1)d(1/k)=ia\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \frac{e^{ika}}{k}$. As far as I understand integral is taken in P.V. sense, and only $\sin ka$ from the integrand survives. $-a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk\frac{\sin ka}{k} =-a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d(ka)\frac{\sin ka}{ka}=-\pi a$ for $a>0$. For $a<0$ you get an additional minus - you integrate from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ instead

Answer (score 3):

The convenience in notation, let denote $k = t$ and $x - x'  = x$. Now, we're left to prove that:
$$J = \frac1{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itx} - 1}{t^2}dt = -\frac{|x|}{2}$$
Consider the following integral on the contour $C$ of 2 semicircle in the upper half plane with center at $0$ and have $R, \epsilon$ as radius:
$$I = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{C} \frac{e^{izx} - 1}{z^2}dz$$
Since it is obvious that $\vert e^{izx} - 1 \vert \leq \vert e^{izx} \vert +1 = 2$, one can see that the integral of the semicirl with radius $R$ will go to $0$. Moreover, there is no pole inside our contour:
$$I = 0 \Rightarrow J - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac1{2\pi} \int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{e^{izx} - 1}{z^2}dz $$
$$\Rightarrow J = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac1{2\pi} \int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{e^{izx} - 1}{z^2}dz = \frac{i}{2}\text{Res} \left(\frac{e^{izx} - 1}{z^2}\right) = - \frac{x}{2}$$
Note that the above is valid for $ x > 0 $. Otherwise, we will consider two semicircle in the lower half plane which will eventually yield:
$ J = \frac{x}{2}$.
Hence:
$$J = - \frac{\vert x \vert }{2}$$